# how to add chart in visual studio 2012 c# windows based application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi, I am newbie in visual studio .net  I am developing a project of energy consumption calculator in which I am drawing the two annual energy cost in xy chart like energycost1 and energycost2 .
I drag the chart from toolbox into window form and I wanted to show these two energy cost on this chart. on `x-axis` I want to show nothing but on `y-axis` I wanted to show the energy values like this `200k , 400k , 600k , 800k 1M`.
can anyone help me to create this chart for me I have no idea how to draw these two value on chart.

Comment: Microsoft has a good set of docs on it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

Comment: you can use zedgraph or nplot or other library.

Comment: am curious if you figured out a solution to this problem. Any luck?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the axis properties for the chart you have created (let's call it chData).

```
chData.Titles.Add("Voltage Data");
chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Readings";
chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Voltage (V)";
```

Or you can add a secondary axis:

```
chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Title = "Current (A)";
```

There are a ton of properties you can play with, just check the Axis libraries for a full list. In there are the properties for intervals, manually adding tick titles, etc.

To add individual series, use the following code:

```
chData.Series.Add("Battery 1");
```

then you can add data points to it like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataSize - 1; i++)
 {
     chData.Series[0].Points.Add(array[i]);
 }
```

where array[] is the array that has your data you want to show in it. You can change the visual type of chart and most other properties from the property window under Series.